# Swift mac app -> Moving cursor closes NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra

I am new MAC application development using swift. I have a NSViewController with different menu options.

In which, I have one NSWindow open already and tapping "Window" menu option, opening another window.

```
let passwordVC = PasswordViewController()
        let pwdWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: passwordVC)
        pwdWindow.title = "Password"
        pwdWindow.orderFront(self)
        let controller = NSWindowController(window: pwdWindow)

        controller.showWindow(self)
```

but it closes automatically when I start moving cursor. I am doing nothing, it stays. I am not sure what is the issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using like this. And it works for me. Seems to be an alternate way.

```
 let passwordVC = PasswordViewController()
        let pwdWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: passwordVC)
        pwdWindow.title = "Password"
        let application = NSApplication.shared()
        application.runModal(for: pwdWindow)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or is this a solution to your problem above?  It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the posted code, your window is going out of scope, which will destroy it. Try retaining the window in a higher scoped variable. Like as a class property:

```
class Controller: NSViewController {
    var pwdWindow: NSWindow!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        pwdWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: passwordVC)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I get this build error "class declaration cannot close over value "passwordVC" defined in Outer scope."

Comment: Ah, that is implementation specific. I'm not sure why that would happen. I would need to see the code to help figure out why.